# Display a list of google maps search in a tableview

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps

I want to run a search for nearest shopping mall then add the results in a tableview where the user can see a list of all shopping malls in their area along with a small image sorted from nearest to furthest and can click on any result to get more information and open through google-maps. Any idea on how I can do that? I took a look and the google-maps places API, would that help?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that would help.. you would have to create an object. With UIImage and label for mall name and detail.. and then create an array of that object.. to populate your table view.. and don’t forget to follow UITableViewDelegate and data source

Comment: Could you please provide more details as to how I can achieve this because I'm new to swift.

Answer (score 0):

**in PlaceViewController**

```
fileprivate var placesList:[Place] = []
fileprivate let tblPlaceCellId = "tblPlaceCellId"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupView()
}

//MARK: Components
let tblPlaces:UITableView = {
    let tbl = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
    return tbl
}()

//MARK: Setup UI
func setupView() {
    view.addSubview(tblPlaces)
    tblPlaces.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        tblPlaces.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        tblPlaces.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        tblPlaces.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        tblPlaces.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    ])

    tblPlaces.delegate = self
    tblPlaces.dataSource = self
    tblPlaces.register(PlaceCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: tblPlaceCellId)
}
```

}

**Add UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource to PlaceViewController**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return placesList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tblPlaceCellId, for: indexPath) as! PlaceCell
    //You can add data to row
    /*
     let item = placeList[indexPath.row]
     cell.lblTitle = item.name
     */
    return cell
}
```

**Create Struct for Place Object**

```
struct Place {
    let id:Int
    let name:String
    let image:UIImage
    let detail:String
}
```

**Create UITableView Cell**

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Design your Place Row cell
}
```

Comment: But how can I get the locations of the nearest shopping mall?

Comment: you have to use Google place API NearBy Search [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests)

Comment: This API is in JavaScript. How do I implement this into swift?

Comment: You can use Cocoapods [link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start)